# IndexError: list index out of range(For Loop, enumerate)

Tags: for-loop, enumerate, index-error

I need to assign some colour indexes to some labels fro which I am using below code that is giving me index error. Please suggest changes in code.

```
formation_colours=['#F4D03F', '#F5B041']
formation_labels = ['Sh', 'SS']

formation_color_map = {}
for ind, label in enumerate(formation_labels):
    formation_color_map[label] = formation_colours[ind]
```

Comment: Is there any more relevant code?

Comment: This works fine in python 3.6. The code looks fine to me